# Excel sheet dynamic summing condition based

Tags: excel, dynamic, conditional-statements

Say I have the following numbers in cells in suceeding rows of column B 1,24,23,12,15,17. How do I get Excel to only add up to that cell so that the sum equals a predefined number (say 25) and return the corresponding row number at which this condition is satisfied?

In the example above, it should add B1 and B24 whose result equals the predefined number (25) and return row 2 as a result.

The challenge is unlike SUMIF and similar commands, I cannot prescribe a range B1:B6 or so. Instead of B6 it should be some number Bx where x (2 in this case) is decided on the fly. Does that make sense?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it with a single formula, but you can do it by adding a column with running totals. See this code example:

[image: Code Example Screenshot]

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am able to progress with my work. Just one more related question. What if the number we are trying to match is not a result of the sum of one or more cells. Say for instance I wanted to match how many rows I will have to add up to arrive at a figure of 28 (instead of 25) what function other than MATCH should I use? Can I use a similar formula to return 2 in cell E1 in this case too ?   I could then use the running total column to find the difference between 28 and 25 (i.e 3) and use the difference (if any) 3 with another formula in another cell.